# Find the smallest power of 2 greater than or equal to n in Python

Tags: python

What is the simplest function to return the smallest power of 2 that is greater than or equal to a given non-negative integer in Python?

For example, the smallest power of 2 greater than or equal to 6 is 8.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Let's test it:

```
import collections
import math
import timeit

def power_bit_length(x):
    return 2**(x-1).bit_length()

def shift_bit_length(x):
    return 1<<(x-1).bit_length()

def power_log(x):
    return 2**(math.ceil(math.log(x, 2)))

def test(f):
    collections.deque((f(i) for i in range(1, 1000001)), maxlen=0)

def timetest(f):
    print('{}: {}'.format(timeit.timeit(lambda: test(f), number=10),
                          f.__name__))

timetest(power_bit_length)
timetest(shift_bit_length)
timetest(power_log)
```

The reason I'm using `range(1, 1000001)` instead of just `range(1000000)` is that the `power_log` version will fail on `0`. The reason I'm using a small number of reps over a largeish range instead of lots of reps over a small range is because I expect that different versions will have different performance over different domains. (If you expect to be calling this with huge thousand-bit numbers, of course, you want a test that uses those.)

With Apple Python 2.7.2:

```
4.38817000389: power_bit_length
3.69475698471: shift_bit_length
7.91623902321: power_log
```

With Python.org Python 3.3.0:

```
6.566169916652143: power_bit_length
3.098236607853323: shift_bit_length
9.982460380066186: power_log
```

With pypy 1.9.0/2.7.2:

```
2.8580930233: power_bit_length
2.49524712563: shift_bit_length
3.4371240139: power_log
```

I believe this demonstrates that the `2**` is the slow part here; using `bit_length` instead of `log` does speed things up, but using `1<<` instead of `2**` is more important.

Also, I think it's clearer. The OP's version requires you to make a mental context-switch from logarithms to bits, and then back to exponents. Either stay in bits the whole time (`shift_bit_length`), or stay in logs and exponents (`power_log`).

Comment: Please note that the result is **incorrect** for `x == 0`, since `(-1).bit_length() == 1` in Python.

Comment: Take care about accuracy. `math.log(2**29,2)` is 29.000000000000004 so `power_log(2**29)` gives an incorrect answer of 30.

Comment: @ColonelPanic The problem you noted is non-existent if `math.log2` is used, as it rightfully should be. The problem exists starting at 29 only if `math.log` is used.

Comment: On Windows with Python 3.10.8, using 10,000 random numbers, the relative times are a bit different: 0.3 for shift_bit_length, 0.7 for power_bit_length, 1.0 for power_log

Answer (score 24):

Always returning `2**(x - 1).bit_length()` is incorrect because although it returns 1 for x=1, it returns a non-monotonic 2 for x=0. A simple fix that is monotonically safe for x=0 is:

```
def next_power_of_2(x):  
    return 1 if x == 0 else 2**(x - 1).bit_length()
```

Sample outputs:

```
>>> print(', '.join(f'{x}:{next_power_of_2(x)}' for x in range(10)))
0:1, 1:1, 2:2, 3:4, 4:4, 5:8, 6:8, 7:8, 8:8, 9:16
```

It can pedantically be argued that x=0 should return 0 (and not 1), since `2**float('-inf') == 0`.

Comment: Isn't that awfully slow for large `x`? Apart from that, I can't say I understand it.

Comment: @delnan -- Why would you expect this to be slow? (not that I understand the code either ...)

Comment: @delnan: First, `bit_length` is effectively log base 2 rounded up - 1, and very quickly. So, raise 2 to the power of that, and you're done. Maybe doing `1 <<` instead of `2 **` would be faster, but otherwise, what slowness are you expecting here?

Comment: I'm not sure how python implements bit_length, but it's pretty much instant even for huge values of `x`.

Comment: bit_length returns "Number of bits necessary to represent self in binary."

Comment: Nevermind, I read this as taking 2 to the `x-1`th power, then taking the `bit_length` of that. It's actually the other way around. With that, the intermediate integer would get quite large quickly, but this way it's more reasonable. Still not what I'd call intuitive.

Comment: @delnan: Once you make the switch in your head from powers of 2 to bits, it makes sense. It might be better to make that more explicit somehow (although I'm not exactly sure how, other than a comment. Any suggestions?). Or, if the 2:1 speedup (even smaller in Py3 and PyPy) isn't relevant, maybe the `math.log` version is better, but see the comments there.

Answer (score 19):

Would this work for you:

```
import math

def next_power_of_2(x):
    return 1 if x == 0 else 2**math.ceil(math.log2(x))
```

Note that `math.log2` is available in Python 3 but not in Python 2. Using it instead of `math.log` avoids numerical problems with the latter at 2**29 and beyond.

Sample outputs:

```
>>> print(', '.join(f'{x}:{next_power_of_2(x)}' for x in range(10)))
0:1, 1:1, 2:2, 3:4, 4:4, 5:8, 6:8, 7:8, 8:8, 9:16
```

It can pedantically be argued that x=0 should return 0 (and not 1), since `2**float('-inf') == 0`.

Comment: Requires log, which I think is slower.

Comment: @jhoyla Performance is very rarely relevant (and the slow part would be looking up two functions and calling them, not `log` specifically). This is definitely more readable and obvious (for me at least).

Comment: The only way to find out if it's slower is to test… but it does have the disadvantage that it says `next_power_of_two(0)` is  a `DomainError` instead of 1…

Comment: @jhoyla: Oh, good point. There's an easy fix for each version, but I'm not sure which one looks clearer once fixed… (Also, it's arguable that `next_power_of_two(0)` should be `0`, not `1`, because `0` is the `-inf`th power, and therefore also the `-inf+1`th… But either way, `2` is clearly wrong.)

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, I know this question is old and my answer is pretty simple, but I am really surprised in all this time nobody posted it here, so I will post it as an answer.

The easiest solution is really simple, no need to import any library, you can do it in one loop if you use ***`while`*** statement!

So the logic is very simple, create a variable with a value of 1, while the value of the variable is less than the number, multiply the variable by 2!

Code:

```
i = 1
while i < n: i *=2
```

The return values for n = 1, 63, 64, 255, 256, 1000, 4095:

```
2, 64, 64, 256, 256, 1024, 4096
```

This can be easily modified to calculate the next power closet to a number of other bases as well:

```
def nextpower(num, base):
  i = 1
  while i < num: i *= base
  return i
```

Answer (score 3):

We can do this as follows using bit manipulation:

```
def next_power_of_2(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    if n & (n - 1) == 0:
        return n
    while n & (n - 1) > 0:
        n &= (n - 1)
    return n << 1
```

Sample outputs:

```
>>> print(', '.join(f'{x}:{next_power_of_2(x)}' for x in range(10)))
0:1, 1:1, 2:2, 3:4, 4:4, 5:8, 6:8, 7:8, 8:8, 9:16
```

For further reading, refer to [this resource](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/smallest-power-of-2-greater-than-or-equal-to-n/).

Answer (score 0):

```
v+=(v==0);
v--;
v|=v>>1;
v|=v>>2;
v|=v>>4;
v|=v>>8;
v|=v>>16;
v++;
```

For a 16-bit integer.

Comment: bit-twiddling hacks are great but please cite sources

Comment: 1) It is not python code
2) It is slower than the slowes proposed method (power_log)