# Zero-padding data until its length is equal to a power of 2

Tags: python, performance, function

I'm trying to write a function that can zero-pad some data until its length is equal to the closest higher power of 2. I also want to be able to do a certain number of iterations of this. Right now this is my function:

```
def pad_to_next_2n(array, iterations = 1):
    n = 1
    while n <= iterations:
        l = len(array)
        padding = l +1 #incase array is already length equal to 2^n
        while np.log2(padding) % 1 != 0:
            padding += 1
        if l % 2 == 0:
            total_padding = padding - l
            array =  np.pad(array, (total_padding/2,), 'constant')
            n += 1
        else:
            total_padding = padding - l
            left_padding = (total_padding - 1)/2
            right_padding = total_padding - left_padding
            print total_padding
            print left_padding
            print right_padding
            array = np.pad(array, (left_padding, right_padding), 'constant')
            n += 1
    return array
```

This does work but it's really slow for iterations higher than 5. I was wondering if anyone could help to improve the speed of this or see a better way to do it. I believe the biggest problem is coming from the

```
while np.log2(padding) % 1 != 0:
                padding += 1
```

Part but I'm not sure how to make that more efficient.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by " I always want to be able to do a certain number of iterations of this.". Why not calculate the final size in one go (`2**(int(np.log2(padding))+1)` could do that) and then pad the array?

Comment: I meant also not always, it was a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to do a lot of what you are doing - you just want to find out the next power of 2 that you need to extend the length of your array to, and then you can call `pad` on the array to pad it to the length you need in one go.

This uses [`shift_bit_length`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267555/how-can-i-find-the-smallest-power-of-2-greater-than-n-in-python) from another question about fastest way to get next power of 2 in Python.

```
import numpy as np

def shift_bit_length(x):
    return 1<<(x-1).bit_length()

def padpad(data, iterations = 1):
    narray = data
    for i in xrange(iterations):
        length = len(narray)
        diff = shift_bit_length(length + 1) - length
        if length % 2 == 0:
            pad_width = diff / 2
        else:
            # need an uneven padding for odd-number lengths
            left_pad = diff / 2
            right_pad = diff - left_pad
            pad_width = (left_pad, right_pad)
        narray = np.pad(narray, pad_width, 'constant')
    return narray
```

Some tests:

```
>> arr = np.array([1, 2])

>> padpad(arr, 1)
Out[2]: array([0, 1, 2, 0])

>> len(padpad(arr, 1)
Out[3]: 4

>> padpad(arr, 5)
Out[4]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

>> len(padpad(arr, 5))
Out[5]: 32

>> padpad(arr, 8)
Out[6]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: This only works for arrays that have an even length. Would it be able to work with odd-length arrays?

Comment: @greenthumbtack Whoops - added in code (adapted from your original) which supports odd-length arrays.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to iterate by growing the padding by one each time. Just calculate what's the next size you need. The next size in total is `2**int(log2(current_size)+1)`.

Then you can just subtract `current_size` and know how much padding you need.

Comment: FYI, [`int`/`long`'s `.bit_length()` method (available in 2.7+)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length) can compute the bits required to represent a value more efficiently/directly (and avoid admittedly unlikely floating point errors). `1 << current_size.bit_length()` appears to be equivalent (except when `current_size == 0`; `log2` throws exception, `.bit_length()` returns `0`; you could force it to return `1` without affect behavior in other scenarios by doing `(current_size | 1).bit_length()`).