# How much data are there in an interval?

Tags: python, pandas

**I have a list object,i want to know that how many numbers are in a particular interval?The code is as follows**

```
a = [1, 7, 4, 7, 4, 8, 5, 2, 17, 8, 3, 12, 9, 6, 28]
interval = 3
a = list(map(lambda x:int(x/interval),a))
for i in range(min(a),max(a)+1):
    print(i*interval,(i+1)*interval,':',a.count(i))
```

**Output**

```
0 3 : 2
3 6 : 4
6 9 : 5
9 12 : 1
12 15 : 1
15 18 : 1
18 21 : 0
21 24 : 0
24 27 : 0
27 30 : 1
```

**Is there a simple way to get this information?The simpler the better**

Comment: Look at `numpy.histogram` or `pandas.cut`

Answer (score 3):

Now that we're talking about performance, I'd like to offer my **numpy solution using [bincount](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html)**:

```
import numpy as np

interval = 3
a = [1, 7, 4, 7, 4, 8, 5, 2, 17, 8, 3, 12, 9, 6, 28]
l = max(a) // interval + 1
b = np.bincount(a, minlength=l*interval).reshape((l,interval)).sum(axis=1)
```

(`minlength` is necessary just to be able to reshape if `max(a)` isn't a multiple of interval)

With the lables taken from Erfan's answer we get:

```
rnge = range(0, max(a) + interval + 1, interval)
lables = [f'[{i}-{j})' for i, j in zip(rnge[:-1], rnge[1:])]

for l,b in zip(lables,b):
    print(l,b)

[0-3) 2
[3-6) 4
[6-9) 5
[9-12) 1
[12-15) 1
[15-18) 1
[18-21) 0
[21-24) 0
[24-27) 0
[27-30) 1
```

This is much faster than the pandas solution.

### **Performance and scaling comparison**

In order to assess the scaling capability, I just replaced `a = [1, ..., 28] * n` and timed the execution (without imports and printing) for n = 1, 10, 100, 1K, 10K and 100K:

[image]

(python 3.7.3 on win32 / pandas 0.24.2 / numpy 1.16.2)

Comment: @jezrael: I guess this wouldn't principally change the picture, as the trend is already clearly visible. But I can try and add some more test.

Comment: ok, let me know after test, also [perfplot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot) should be used here

Comment: @jezrael: I've updated the tests for list lengths up to 1.5 million elements. Starting from n = 1K (15000 elements) there's no more qualitative change between the three algorithms, so I expect the lines to keep running parallel in the log-log-plot even for still bigger values of n.

Answer (score 2):

#### Pandas solution with `pd.cut` and `groupby`

```
s = pd.Series(a)
bins = pd.cut(s, range(0, s.max() + interval, interval), right=False)
s.groupby(bins).count()
```

```
[0, 3)      2
[3, 6)      4
[6, 9)      5
[9, 12)     1
[12, 15)    1
[15, 18)    1
[18, 21)    0
[21, 24)    0
[24, 27)    0
[27, 30)    1
dtype: int64
```

---

To get cleaner bins results, we can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53316739/assign-bucket-ranges-in-power-of-2-in-a-separate-column-in-pandas/53317057#53317057) method from linked answer:

```
s = pd.Series(a)
rnge = range(0, s.max() + interval, interval)
labels = [f'{i}-{j}' for i, j in zip(rnge[:-1], rnge[1:])]
bins = pd.cut(s, range(0, s.max() + interval, interval), right=False, labels=labels)
s.groupby(bins).count()
```

```
0-3      2
3-6      4
6-9      5
9-12     1
12-15    1
15-18    1
18-21    0
21-24    0
24-27    0
27-30    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line using a dictionary comprehension :

```
a = [1, 7, 4, 7, 4, 8, 5, 2, 17, 8, 3, 12, 9, 6, 28]

{"[{};{}[".format(x, x+3) : len( [y  for y in a if y >= x and y < x+3] ) 
 for x in range(min(a), max(a), 3)}
```

Output :

```
{'[1;4[': 3,
 '[4;7[': 4,
 '[7;10[': 5,
 '[10;13[': 1,
 '[13;16[': 0,
 '[16;19[': 1,
 '[19;22[': 0,
 '[22;25[': 0,
 '[25;28[': 0}
```

---

> Performance comparison :
>
> Pandas solution with pd.cut and groupby : **8.51 ms** ± 32 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
>
> Dictionary comprehension : **19.7 µs** ± 37.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
>
> Using np.bincount : **22.4** µs ± 263 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

Comment: You solution might be good for small data since it skip all the pandas overhead. But it is slow for larger data due to lack of vectorization (try `1e4` data points and you would see the difference).

Comment: You're right list and dictionnary comprehensions don't scale as well as vectorization functions. But they are often overlooked as a consequence when they should be prioritized when you have small data, as you see it's 1000 times faster

Comment: @vlemaistre could you include [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56953697/3944322) in your performance comparison. At least at my computer it's way faster than the pandas solution. Can you verify this?

Comment: @Stef I included it. It is indeed 2.5 times faster than using pandas cut and groupby

Comment: @vlemaistre Thank you. On Windows 32bit python 3.7 / pandas 0.24.2 / numpy 1.16.2 I get per performance difference of 100 times. Do you have any idea why there is so big a difference between different installations?

Comment: We should have similar results it's weird. I executed everything from the creation of the array a to the end result for all of the methods. How did you proceed ?

Comment: I did the same, except for the printing of the results. See [here](https://pastebin.com/7FMeygn6) for the exact code and results.

Comment: You're right, I get the same thing when I remove the print ! My bad for including the print I should've removed it, I'll update your result.