# Matlab nextpow2(A) in Python

Tags: python, matlab

In Matlab, P = nextpow2(A) returns the exponents for the smallest powers of two that satisfy

2^p≥|A|
for each element in A.

```
a = [1 -2 3 -4 5 9 519];
p = nextpow2(a) returns
```

p = 1×7

```
 0     1     2     2     3     4    10
```

Calculate the positive next powers of 2.

`np2 = 2.^p`  returns
np2 = 1×7

1           2           4           4           8          16        1024

I need to have the exact functionality with Python so that I can calculate this:

```
 mag = sqrt(flow(:,:,1).^2+flow(:,:,2).^2)*scale+128;
```

where flow is the optical flow, meaning a velocity vector field at the size of the image, where each element shows the disparity as distance from one axes:so flow is (U1,U2) where U1.shape = (227,227) U2.shape=  (227,227)

Is there a function in Python libraries? Or how I can write it the same way as it if (input is a matrix)

Comment: `nextpow2(x)` is just `ceil(log2(abs(x)))`

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14267555/2586922) for some ideas (non-matrix input)

Comment: what about: 
```def nextpow2(p):
    n = 2; while p < n: 
n *= 2; return n ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the smallest power of 2 greater than or equal to n in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267555/find-the-smallest-power-of-2-greater-than-or-equal-to-n-in-python)